# route name and directory name conflict in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is it possible to have same name for both route as well a directory in node.js project? For e.g.

`require("./test")(router);`

And inside test.js file

`app.get("/test", function(req, res) {});`

Also **test** is a directory in the same project.

When I try accessing url **localhost:8443/test**, it leads to following error:

**The URL had the following error Error: EISDIR, read.**

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what router library (if any) you are using and how and where you mount your public directory.

For example you do something like:

```
// Files
server.js
// Directories
lib
public
- test
```

and mount for example in express via

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

the public directory. Now when you have a route named `/test` and a folder named test in public it matters if you first called

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

or defined

```
app.get("/test", function(req, res, next) {
  res.send("ok")
});
```

in server.js

If you mount your static directory first it will match the directory and if you defined the controller first it will match the route.

What you could do it you match the route first and if for some reason you want to match the file you call

```
next();
```

I hope this was kinda understandable.

Comment: Thanks @Taner. That was really helpful.